# Compare objects containing arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have two JS objects which contain some arrays. I'd like to compare the two objects and create a third object, containing arrays only unique to `secondObj`.

They look like this:

```
firstObj : {
    Jim_Array : [...],
    Joe_Array : [...],
    Bill_Array : [...]
}

secondObj : {
    Bill_Array : [...],
    Sam_Array : [...],
    Kate_Array : [...],
    Jim_Array : [...],
    Joe_Array : [...]
}
```

I'd like to compare the two objects and end up with the following:

```
thirdObj : {
    Sam_Array : [...],
    Kate_Array : [...]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: The above flag was a mistake on my part. Please disregard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like following

```
var thirdObj = {};
for (var key in secondObj) {
  if(!firstObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     // In case you need to compare the array additional check will come here
     thirdObj[key] = secondObj[key];

  }

}
```

Another way

```
var thirdObj = {};
for (var key in secondObj) {
  if(firstObj[key] === undefined) {
     // In case you need to compare the array additional check will come here
     thirdObj[key] = secondObj[key];

  }

}
```

Comment: The first option is very similar to something I was working on, but better. Thanks, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()` with `reduce()` and check if firstObj has property of secondObj with `hasOwnProperty()`, if not add to new object.

```js
var firstObj = {Jim_Array : ['...'], Joe_Array : ['...'], Bill_Array : ['...']}
var secondObj = {Bill_Array : ['...'], Sam_Array : ['...'], Kate_Array : ['...'], Jim_Array : ['...'], Joe_Array : ['...']}

var result = Object.keys(secondObj).reduce(function(o, e) {
  if(!firstObj.hasOwnProperty(e)) o[e] = secondObj[e];
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using underscore:

```
var result = _.pick(secondObj, _.difference( _.keys(secondObj), _.keys(firstObj)));
```